# How redirect input while process is running?

Tags: bash, io-redirection, stdin

I have an interactive application that takes input from the keyboard.

Whenever I run the application I always write the same things in the beginning. So I was thinking I could make a file with those things and redirect them to the application with:

```
myapplication < myinput.txt
```

The problem is that when I am done with that I want to give control back to the keyboard so I can type the rest of the input. Is it possible? I don't mind using a bash script.

Comment: Your app must handle that. After program start, when it hits EOF on fd 0, it should close it and open `/dev/tty` for reading. Then you can start consuming lines from the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about that one, but if the command you want to use is a simple non-interactive one, and you just want to types things into it (and prepend those with the content of 'myinput.txt', try:

```
cat myinput.txt - | command
```

ex:

```
cat myinput.txt - | grep something
```

But if you need more complicated interaction, you should probably use `expect` (which is not trivial to use at first, but very powerful).

Comment: Thanks. However I want firstly the myinput.txt to be sent to the command and after that be able and type things.

Comment: The command I show above will : first output content of "myinput.txt" and then output content of "-" (which, here, for cat, means the standard input, ie what you'll type next). Try if it works, but as I said, it's limited and not very friendly (especially if the command you type into is something like a visual editor, etc). ex:  `cat myinput.txt - | ssh user@host` works more or less. Finish by typing "exit" and return, and it should exit the ssh... (put : ls -al *followed by a return*, in myinput.txt, for example)

Comment: You're right. It actually works. Thanks a dozen :)

Comment: Enjoy :)  (and note that the '-' notation is used in many unix utilities, for example tar, grep, etc., and is usefull for many things)